# Determining current rendition for HTML5 HLS streams

Tags: html, video, http-live-streaming, m3u8

I've got an HTML5 `<video>` element whose source is a `.m3u8` ([HLS stream](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/networkinginternet/conceptual/streamingmediaguide/Introduction/Introduction.html))

I have an M3U8 with three different renditions: `640x360`, `960x540`, and `1280x720`

On Desktops I have a Flash Player for playing the video, so the HTML5 fallback is only intended for mobile (iOS and Android) - I am doing all of my testing on an iPad and, once it's working, I will try it out on Android and hope everything works the same.

My goal is to, at any point in time, figure out what rendition the video element is playing. The rendition is subject to change as the user's bandwidth changes.

I tried using the `.videoHeight` property, but it always returns 480 regardless of the rendition being downloaded - which is particularly odd because 480 isn't even an option.

Does anyone know how I can figure out the rendition being downloaded?

Comment: Maybe you're reading the .videoHeight property too soon. You need to read it during an event, perhaps loadedmetadata.

Comment: This page gives a good way to interact with the video element: http://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html

Comment: @vipw I actually have a simulated "cue point" event that I'm creating (a `setInterval` runs every 0.25 seconds, checking to see if the current time is between x and x+0.3) - every 10 seconds I check the `.videoHeight` property, and every time it's 480.

Comment: I wouldn't rule out that it's a bug in the web browser. HTML5 video support is still very much in the early days. I suppose you can file a bug with Apple.

Comment: @vipw You're right, after lots of testing I've confirmed it's a bug - although I believe it's a bug in QuickTime and not with Safari. It seems like Safari just embeds a QuickTime element and pings it for information about the video. When handed a stream with multiple different video qualities, QuickTime will return an incorrect value for `.videoHeight`. Interestingly enough QuickTime itself reports the proper quality, so it's **only** an issue with the browser plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cleaning up some old questions that never received answers:

Unfortunately this one is just not possible. The HTMl5 video spec and HTML5 video implementations in most browsers are intended to abstract away **all** of the underlying magic involved in playing videos. You give it a source, it plays. Everything else is completely hidden and you have no access. No access to metadata channels, no access to audio channels, no access to bitrate and resolution information,...

At best I developed a solution to **guess** which resolution was playing. Every 10 seconds a 1 MB file was loaded over AJAX. I measured the speed at which this downloaded to guess at their current bandwidth. I know that QuickTime will only play a rendition if you have double the required bandwidth. So if the `960x540` rendition requires 1400 kbit/s then it won't play unless you have 2800 kbit/s bandwidth.

It's not very good (and wastes 6 MB of bandwidth per minute) but it's better than nothing.